# AWS - automatically pick new versions of a container

Tags: dockerhub, amazon-ec2

Ok, so I have created an EC2 Container Service cluster, a task definition and I was able to run the task. It's a very simple website in a container. Whenever I push any changes to Bitbucket, Docker Hub picks up the source and builds a new image. The task definition in AWS points to this automatically built docker image; however it picks it only when starting. When the image changes nothing happens.

What do I need to do to make EC2 CS constantly pick up the latest container version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you restart your ECS Container Instance, it will pull the latest image (provided you have not specified a tag, else it will pull the last version of your tagged image).

If you want to deploy the new version of the image, the best thing to do is to create a new version of your task definition, without changing anything and then to update your service and pick the last task definition version you just created.

It is documented in the second paragraph of this page :
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/update-service.html

Comment: Restarting is ok - I already knew that. I was wondering if it is possible for this to happen automatically, i.e. without me restarting the instance every time. It's not a big issue anyway. Thanks for the info.

Comment: You can automatize it, by making two calls to the AWS API to : 1) create new task definition (but not changing anything to it) and 2) update the service task to the one you created

Comment: I guess I still have to learn a lot about AWS. So basically I need to make an app/script that both pushes the code and makes an AWS API request for the points above? Currently I don't have the time to test this out, but I looked at the API docs and it seems doable. Thanks a lot.